# What is the equation of a reflected Bézier curve?

Tags: symmetry, bezier-curve, reflection

As shown in [this linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqObv.jpg), I would like to know the equation of a bezier curve (both quadratic and cubic) reflected (or should I say symmetric) about a line joining both ends (A and B) of the curve.

Comment: I would really appreciate a reason for the downvote

Comment: Never mind.  There are some down-vote maniacs around here… And welcome to  Maths SX!

Comment: Equation in terms of what? "Reflect the control points through the line" is the practical solution to the underlying problem, but doesn't answer the question you've asked.